# UIImageView subclass doesn't work simultaneously gesture

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uiimageview, subclass

I'm developing a iOs 6 app for iPad. I've developed a UIImageView subclass adding gesture recognizing (zoom, pinch and pan), but I've a problem: it doesn't admit simultaneously gestures. I first code it as a normal UIImageView, and it worked great, but now with the subclass it doesn't. My code:

image.m (UIImageView subclass)

```
- (id)initWithImage:(UIImage *)image {
self = [super initWithImage:image];

if (self) {

    [self setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];
    [self setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panDetected:)];
    [super addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];

    UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchRecognizer = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pinchDetected:)];
    [super addGestureRecognizer:pinchRecognizer];

    UIRotationGestureRecognizer *rotationRecognizer = [[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rotationDetected:)];
    [super addGestureRecognizer:rotationRecognizer];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapDetected:)];
    tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    [super addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];

    NSLog(@"lkjlkj");
}
return self;}

- (void)panDetected:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panRecognizer {
CGPoint translation = [panRecognizer translationInView:self.superview];
CGPoint imageViewPosition = self.center;
imageViewPosition.x += translation.x;
imageViewPosition.y += translation.y;

self.center = imageViewPosition;
[panRecognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView: self.superview];}

  - (void)pinchDetected:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)pinchRecognizer{    

CGFloat scale = pinchRecognizer.scale;
self.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.transform, scale, scale);
pinchRecognizer.scale = 1.0;}

- (void)rotationDetected:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *)rotationRecognizer{
CGFloat angle = rotationRecognizer.rotation;
self.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.transform, angle);
rotationRecognizer.rotation = 0.0;}

- (void)tapDetected:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapRecognizer{
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
    self.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.superview.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(self.superview.bounds));
    self.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
}];}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{
return YES;}
```

viewcontroller.m (where I create a imageview from image which doesn't respond to multiple gestures simultaneously)

```
image *img = [[image alloc] initWithImage:imatgetemporal];    
img.center = CGPointMake(525/2, 651/2);


[[self.view viewWithTag:2] addSubview:img];
```

Thanks for all!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you can solve it by adding the same delegate to the `UIPanGestureRecognizer`, `UIPinchGestureRecognizer`, `UIRotationGestureRecognizer` and to the `UITapGestureRecognizer` just after declaring them. The code would be like this:

```
tapRecognizer.delegate = self;
pinchRecognizer.delegate = self;
rotationRecognizer.delegate = self;
tapRecognizer.delegate = self;
```

Hope it helps.